# Weblogic Deployment Error

Tags: web-applications, deployment, weblogic

When i deploy my working application on Weblogic, i get a Stack Over Flow error:

```
###<Sep 5, 2011 3:56:43 AM EDT> <Error> <Console> <qdcls0757> <CorpDEVAdmin> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <wlsadm9> <> <> <1315209403700> <BEA-240003> <Console encountered the following error java.lang.Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.adminserver.AdminRequestStatus.includeDeploymentFailure(AdminRequestStatus.java:1100)   at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.adminserver.AdminRequestStatus.signalCancelSucceeded(AdminRequestStatus.java:1042)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.statemachines.adminserver.AwaitingCancelResponses.signalCancelCompletion(AwaitingCancelResponses.java:130)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.statemachines.adminserver.AwaitingCancelResponses.doCancelCompletionCheck(AwaitingCancelResponses.java:112)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.statemachines.adminserver.AwaitingCancelResponses.receivedCancelSucceeded(AwaitingCancelResponses.java:84)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.adminserver.AdminRequestImpl.receivedCancelSucceeded(AdminRequestImpl.java:452)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.transport.CommonMessageReceiver.receiveCancelSucceededMsg(CommonMessageReceiver.java:263)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.transport.CommonMessageReceiver$3.run(CommonMessageReceiver.java:753)
    at weblogic.work.ServerWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(ServerWorkManagerImpl.java:518)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: 
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder.decodeLoop(UTF_8.java:416)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:544)
    at java.lang.StringCoding$CharsetSD.decode(StringCoding.java:190)
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:228)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:405)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:433)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:260)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at weblogic.logging.RotatingFileOutputStream.flush(RotatingFileOutputStream.java:88)`
```

Can anybody help me on this

Comment: the stacktrace also shows a Cancel Deployment - did you fire that or did it happen as part of the deployment?

Answer (score 0):

try changing weblogic logging log level to FATAL from log4j.xml file and then start the server again.

Comment: Y to do this so.. can you please explain the source of this issue... @Ankit